# Unknown authentication strategy jwt in hapijs jwt authentication

Tags: jwt, hapi.js

I am using hapi-auth-jwt for authentication purpose
But on the login when i use auth strategy as jwt, it shows **Unknown authentication strategy jwt in /login**
I am using glue
Here is my code

**manifest.js**:

```
    module.exports      = {
        server        : {},
        connections   : [
            {
                host: apiConfig.server.host,
                port: apiConfig.server.port
            },

        ],
        registrations : [
            {
                'plugin': {
                    register: 'hapi-auth-jwt',
                },
            },
        ]
    };
```

**server.js**:

```
        glue.compose(manifest, manifestOptions, (error, server) => {
            if(error)
                throw error;

            mongoose.connect("mongodb://" + apiConfig.database.host + '/' + apiConfig.database.dbname, (error) => {
                if(error)
                    console.log(error);
                else
                    console.log('mongodb connected');
            });



            server.app.assetsPath = Path.resolve(__dirname, '../assets');

            server.start(() => {
                console.log("Api server running " + server.info.uri);
            });

            server.auth.strategy('jwt', 'jwt', {
                key: apiConfig.authentication.secretKey,
                verifyOptions: {
                    algorithms: ['HS256']
                }
            });
        }
```

**route.js**:

```
    {
        method : 'POST',
        path   : '/login',
        config : {
            auth: {
                  strategy: 'jwt',
               },
            tags       : ['api'],
            description: 'Customer login',
            plugins    : {
                'hapi-swagger': {
                    payloadType: 'form'
                }
            },
            /*validate   : {
                failAction: Relish.failAction,
                options   : {
                    abortEarly: false
                },
                payload   : loginSchema
            },*/
        },
        handler: handler.loginHandler
    }
```

Comment: I couldn't get hapi-auth-jwt to work so I use hapi-auth-jwt2 which is actively maintained.  With that plugin the auth section is just `auth: 'jwt'`, not an object with key strategy.

Comment: Where are you adding routes?

Comment: in the glue's manifest file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was loading my route in the glue manifest, after that only I am registering my auth. So I included the auth registration in glue's manifest before the route registration